# Magento - How can I customize the Contact Us POST action?

Tags: php, magento

A form was customized in my current Magento deploy. The customized form hits `contacts/index/post` to send the contents.

Now, they asked me to customize that so when a successful form post occurs, a custom redirection occurs. However, that would imply editing the `contacts/index/post` entry point (and a kitten would be killed).

I've chosen the alternate path: to change the target url to a new one, after creating it (e.g. `customcontacts/index/post`).

Where should I enter to create such entry point and Where should I enter to get the contents (actually: code/script) of `contacts/index/post`(so I can take the code as a base to create my custom entry point) ?

Answer (score 1):

if you have change action then you need to create an extension `which routing url is customcontacts` and create a Indexcontroller.php  and create action postAction in contolers

More details on how create a module  http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/.

For you work modified config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <!-- start of block -->
        <blocks>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Block</class>
            </custommodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <!-- start of routers
    -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>customcontacts</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

Indexcontroller code should be

```
 <?php
class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{


    public function postAction(){

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
         if ( $post ) {
             $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
             /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
             $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
             try {
                 $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                 $postObject->setData($post);

                 $error = false;

                 if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                     $error = true;
                 }

                 if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                     $error = true;
                 }

                 if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                     $error = true;
                 }
                 if ($error) {
                     throw new Exception();
                 }
                 $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                 /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                 $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                     ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                     ->sendTransactional(
                         Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                         Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                         null,
                         array('data' => $postObject)
                     );

                 if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                 throw new Exception();
                 }

                 $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                 $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                 return;
             } catch (Exception $e) {
                 $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                 $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                 return;
             }

         } else {
             $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }

    }
}
```

$this->_redirect('*/*/'); is

change according to you page url if form page is contacts/index/ then change this

$this->_redirect('contacts/index/')
;
For getting success/failure message add below code

in form page `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>`
Must check

```
 $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
 $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
```

is exist in form action controllers
more

http://freegento.com/doc/d9/d7c/_contacts_2controllers_2_index_controller_8php-source.html

Comment: ty :D have to test it